# RobotFramework default keywords are not displayed in the project

Tags: python, robotframework

Mac OS - 10.15.7
RobotFramework - 4.0.1
Python - 2.7.18 & 3.8.9
Eclipse - Version: 2021-03 (4.19.0)

I have installed the robotframework and the default keywords are not displayed in the project.

[image]

In the Preference > PyDev > Python Interpreter & Preference > Robot Framework > Installed Framework, I tried with both 2.7 & 3.8 and still it was not showing any of them.

Update - 29/04/2021 - FN
I did a fresh installation of python 3.7.7, eclipse, robotframework,etc and created a new project and still not getting them

[image]

Comment: Please don't update the question with the answer. Post it as an answer so that the question shows as answered.

Answer (score 0):

[Solved by the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/67310773/3):

> I downgraded the Robotframework from 4.0.1 to 3.2.2 and after that
> everything worked fine....